# My DataGridView updates temporarily as I stop the program and start it again. But my Access Database remains updated permanently

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, ole, ms-jet-ace

Would there be a chance to solve this problem? Once that I inserted a data from the Database, I wanted to update my DataGridView from the other form. Clearly the datagridview has to update as it SELECT on the table of the Database. But once that I updated the datagridview, I tried closing the system from running and restart it again. But when I checked there it didn't update. It goes like the usual datas that is from the Database. However my database is well updated and the data I inserted from the TextBoxes was there too.

```
Private Sub updateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateBtn.Click
    Dim newtable = New DataTable()
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    datafile = "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\thesis\DATABASE\BookLists.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    Try
        str = "Select * from TVL12"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(newtable)
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    TVL12.BookListTVL.DataSource = newtable

End Sub
```

Here's the code for Updating the DataGridView. Anyone had any ideas why does it only Temporarily updates the DataGridView?

Comment: The trick in c# is to set datasource to null and then back to the table.  Like  TVL12.BookListTVL.DataSource = null;  TVL12.BookListTVL.DataSource = newtable;  I think in vb.net is would be nothing instead of null.

Comment: That would be in updateBtn? If I would analyse it, once that I click update, The DataGridView will reset it's values then goes selecting from the database?

Comment: It just repaint the DGV from the datatable.

Comment: As I tried, still the same.

Comment: I actually do something like this      TVL12.BookListTVL.DataSource = vbNull
        TVL12.BookListTVL.DataSource = newtable
        TVL12.BookListTVL.DataSource.Update() = newtable   but it gets me errors   System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Update' on type 'DataTable' not found.'

Comment: Update pushes data to the database.  You just need to repaint.

Comment: Why are you making a new connection every time you update?  Only connect once!!!  I suspect the ACCESS database is not shared and creating multiple connections would cause issues.

Comment: No I'm not creating multiple connections. Those codes are in the same DGV(BookListTVL). I was really trying to find solution about updating DGV from the Database. After I tried doing what you suggested it still the same.

Comment: So after update the DGV. Once you close the program the datas from DGV would reset and set back to its usual datas? I was worrying that after I finished and exporting this program as an Application would it still be the same process?

Comment: In case there is an exception move the Open() method down into the Try.

Comment: How are you updating the database?  Is it from a different application?  ACCESS is not designed to be multi-user (not shared). So if you are writing to the database at same time as reading you probably will have issues.

Comment: I'm updating the database in just a single application that I'm using. But as I'm talking here is that the DataGridView doesn't permanently update just like my Database.You can see that the DataGridView will SELECT from the database incase it updates.